# Get signer of a contract inside a function

Tags: rust, blockchain, move, smartcontracts, aptos

I need to somehow transfer APT coins to another account from smart contract itself. Here is an issue, because transfer function needs &signer of an sender and that's why I can not send it from contract.

Is there any chance that I can send APT directly from contract itself inside a function by getting &signer somehow, or without it?
I've read a lot of docs, search for it on GitHub and found nothing.
I would appreciate any type of help. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the best way to achieve this is using a [resource account](https://aptos.dev/guides/resource-accounts/). Resource accounts provide a different way to access signing capabilities.

For example, to get the signer for a resource account, you can call `retrieve_resource_account_cap` and `create_signer_with_capability`.

Comment: Thank you for you help, I just want to make it clear, could you look at my implementation and tell me if it's gonna be safe
Creating:
`let signer_capability = resource_account::retrieve_resource_account_cap(owner, source_address);
move_to(owner, Storage { 
data: vector::empty<Round>(),
signer_capability: signer_capability,`

Using:
`let resource_signer = account::create_signer_with_capability(&storage.signer_capability);
*winner = signer::address_of(account);
aptos_account::transfer(&resource_signer, *winner, *pool);`

Some of my code, Storage is a struct where rounds, events, etc.

Comment: It might be better to head to the Aptos Discord and ask this question so we can help you properly: https://discord.com/invite/aptoslabs.

Answer (score 0):

These days the easiest way to do this would be with an object.

1. Create an object. Learn more [here](https://aptos.dev/move/move-on-aptos/objects/creating-objects).
2. Create an account alongside that object. Learn more [here](https://aptos.dev/concepts/accounts).
3. Send coins from the object (assuming you have sent coins to it already).

Overall your code to create the object + account would look like this:

```rust
entry fun create(caller: &signer) {
  // Create an object.
  let caller_address = signer::address_of(caller);
  let constructor_ref = object::create_object(caller_address);
  let object_address = object::address_from_constructor_ref(&constructor_ref);

  // Create an account alongside the object.
  aptos_account::create_account(object_address);

  // Store an ExtendRef alongside the object.
  let object_signer = object::generate_signer(&constructor_ref);
  let extend_ref = object::generate_extend_ref(&constructor_ref);
  move_to(
    &object_signer,
    MyRefs { extend_ref: extend_ref },
  );
}
```

You'll see we store this `MyRefs` struct alongside the object. This is necessary to store the `ExtendRef`, which we need to generate a signer later so we can transfer coins. It looks like this:

```rust
struct MyRefs has key, store {
  extend_ref: ExtendRef,
}
```

The code to transfer funds from the account would look like this:

```rust
entry fun transfer(caller: &signer, obj: Object<Account>, to: address, amount: u64) acquires MyRefs {
  let caller_address = signer::address_of(caller);
  assert!(object::is_owner(obj, caller_address), error::permission_denied(CALLER_NOT_OWNER));
  let obj_address = object::object_address(&obj);
  let my_refs = borrow_global<MyRefs>(obj_address);
  let object_signer = object::generate_signer_for_extending(&my_refs.extend_ref);
  aptos_account::transfer(&object_signer, to, amount);
}
```

This `transfer` function takes in an `Object<Account>`. This assumes you know the object address somehow, e.g. from an API based on indexing. You could store the Object (which is essentially a reference) in a resource on chain attached to your account (e.g. `MyObjectPointerStore`) instead if you wanted.

You can see the full code for this example here: https://github.com/banool/move-examples/tree/main/object_account.